# Drawing the following table

Tags: tables, rules

[image]

How can i produce the above table in latex? The first column width i want to be small. The second and third and fourth i want to be of desired size. Is it possible to do it. Also I want thick lines for column seperator.

The examples here doesn't help me: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

Comment: IMO, this isn't a pleasant table design. The examples in the LaTeX Wiki are prettier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For thicker lines, you can (for example) set `\arrayrulewidth=.3ex` before entering the tabular.  However, it will make all lines (horizontal and vertical) of that width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{.5in}||p{1in}||p{1in}||p{1in}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l||}{S. No.} & Book Name & Author &
  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Publisher}\\
\hline
a & b & c & d\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]